# How do I set a color as a hexadecimal variable?

Tags: c#

I want to make one of those cool little color clocks for myself, that sets the color to a time based variable.

I made the variable "One" as being equal to the time as it's six basic characters, but...

```
System.Drawing.Color time = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + One);
```

^ That gives me the error that "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'TimeColor_Clock.TCC.One'"

How can I get my code to accept my variable? I've tried a few different methods (of which none have worked with the variable) but this really seems like the most direct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're doing this outside of a method. Do it instead in your constructor

```
System.Drawing.Color time;

public MyClass()
{
    time = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + One);
}
```

or a method

```
public void UpdateColor()
{
    time = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + One);
}
```

Comment: Cool! Do you understand what the issue was?

Comment: Nope, not at all, but at least I understand how to work around it now. If you wanted to explain it, I'd be interested, but I'm just happy to get it working. I ended up making a binary color changing clock and turning it into a screen saver... and it works great, thanks to you.